# Maven sonar plugin configurations for findbugs pmd checkstyle cobertura

Tags: maven, sonarqube, findbugs, checkstyle, cobertura

I need some help in setting up code quality plugin for maven project.
I have a multi module project. While I have configured `pmd`, `checkstyle`, `findbugs` and `cobertura` in my build process, and I can generate xml reports for each plugin, I am facing some challenges configuring the sonar plugin in my project.

I am not sure how to approach this problem:

1. Should I reuse the reports generated by these plugins while executing sonar? if so what should my sonar plugin configuration be?
2. If I run sonar with embedded `pmd`, `checkstyle`, `findbugs` and `cobertura` plugins, how do I configure them to run only for specific packages or make `findbugs` analyze on `com.mycompany.-` structure.
3. Lastly I cannot get coverage report in sonar, either running cobertura external to sonar or within sonar.

I have my pom below for review. Any help will be tremendously appreciated.

This is in the plugins section of the build section in my root pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <instrumentation>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com/mycompany/**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>                 
                </instrumentation>
                <formats>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                <includes>
                    <include>com/mycompany/**/*.java</include>                      
                </includes>
                <excludeRoots>
                    <excludeRoot>target/generated-sources/*</excludeRoot>
                </excludeRoots>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <onlyAnalyze>com.mycompany.-</onlyAnalyze>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>com/mycompany/**/*.java</includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) should I reuse the reports generated by these plugins while
>   executing sonar? if so what should my sonar plugin configuration be?

Sonar does not provide a mechansim to reuse reports generated by these plugins.  You could configure the rules through the [quality profiles](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles).

> 2) if I run sonar with embedded pmd, checkstyle, findbugs and cobertura plugins, how do I configure them to run only for specific packages or make findbugs analyze on "com.mycompany.-" structure.

Sonar web UI allows you to specify the exclusion for your findbugs filters. Likewise for cobertura.  Not sure about pmd, checkstyle.

> 3) lastly i cannot get coverage report in sonar, either running cobertura external to sonar or within sonar.

It could be possible due to [jacoco being the default code coverage engine](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3536). You could run `mvn clean verify/install sonar:sonar` as instructed and see if it works.