# How do SonarQube plugins get data for reports?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, sonarqube

I read "Sonar does not provide a mechansim to reuse reports generated by these plugins" (I am interested in PMD and  Checksyle plugin) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910604/maven-sonar-plugin-configurations-for-findbugs-pmd-checkstyle-cobertura).
Does it mean that Sonar build app by itself?

If I configure in my pom:

- **maven-checkstyle-plugin** and **maven-pmd-plugin**
- path to SonarQube server (Checkstyle Plugin and Sonar PMD Plugin are configured in Sonar)

and build application, how will [Sonar Checkstyle Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Checkstyle+Plugin) and [Sonar PMD Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pmd) get the results for reports?

I use Maven 3 and SonarQube 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

Your pom configuration of the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` and `maven-pmd-plugin` have no bearing on the SonarQube analysis. There is no way to feed existing Checkstyle or PMD reports into an analysis.

To use Checkstyle and PMD rules in an analysis, turn those rules on in the relevant Quality Profile (presumably the default one). During the analysis PMD and Checkstyle will be executed automatically if the profile in use contains relevant rules.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that SonarQube does not build app by itself? Does it just "run through" the source code if the profile in use contains relevant rules?

Comment: SonarQube analysis scans source code and sometimes byte code. It does not build anything.